# How do I unit test Javascript files that call library functions defined externally?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Let's say I have my awesome.html file with

```
<head>
<script .. abc-library.js>
<script .. app.js>
</head>
```

and I would like to unit-test my own file, `app.js`.

but inside my `app.js`, I am calling something defined in `abc-library.js`, say like this

```
...
handy_function_from_abcjs("do something here");
...
```

Of course when I load my `awesome.html` in the browser, it works fine because I defined my `handy_function` before `app.js`, so my `app.js` sees it...

But, problem when I run the unit test on `app.js`, because it only loads `app.js` alone, and it will fail because it can't find `handy_function`'s definition.

How is this kind of situation solved in those javascript unit test definitions? This is always encountered right?

I hit into this problem now when I am using `karma` to test out my beginner AngularJS app.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily place `abc-library.js` contents in `app.js`; why make it any more complicated? Remove the code once you're done with your unit-testing. Or you could always do a console.log if/when you run your `awesome.html` file in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... but that won't work in this case. The problem is that I am using karma runner, which basically watches my js files for any changes, the moment I save my app.js file after I modify it, the unit tests run immediately. So you can see that including and removing the contents is not an option. There should be a canonical way of dealing with this situation?

Comment: Try doing a dynamic script load inside app.js then, which loads the other script in as per the requirement. Much like how different modules are loaded in languages like C, Java, PHP etc.